# Xcode 14.1 editor extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, editor, xcode14

We are using dictionaries to hold parameters for network requests on our app.
For example:

```
var params: [String: Any] = [:]
    params["pageSize"] = 20
    params["pageIndex"] = 0
```

We weren't experiencing any issues on Xcode 13, but after updating to Xcode 14 this approach seems to slow down editor extremely. So much so that even deleting a single line takes multiple seconds. Since we cannot change every single network request in our app and continue using Xcode 13 forever, is there a way to fix this issue?

Tried to edit a single line of code in a file that includes lots of dictionaries using Xcode 14, took several seconds instead of being instant.

Comment: Are your colleagues experiencing the same thing on their machines? And by the way, why not just use a dictionary literal to define this whole thing in one shot?

Comment: Preview is too slow. I am dead

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for your answer, my colleagues are also experiencing this issue. We are using Moya for networking in our app, and usage of moya requires returning dictionary values as far as I know.

Comment: how did you conclude that the issue is caused by dictionaries, and not by anything else?

Comment: @Murmeko There's no issue with needing dictionaries, I'm just pointing out that it's really weird to build them up value-by value like this instead of just using a dictionary literal like `let params: [String: Any] = ["pageSize": 20, "pageIndex": 0]`.

Comment: Looks like a regular Xcode performance issue when large file is opened. Could be the one you're editing, or the one opened in another tab or window. @Murmeko, are you sure that's not the case and it's all just about dictionaries?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? for us in many places especially large files with a lot of function parameters the performance from Xcode 13 to Xcode 14 went through the floor to the point of being unusable on i9 macbook with 64 GB RAM

Comment: Xcode 14.3 RC solved this issue for me